# Django response with additional headers returns 500

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-framework

Our application developed in Django needs to pass some additional response headers in certain requests.

We do so this way:

```
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       original_response = Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
       original_response['X-Status-Type'] = 'info'
       original_response['X-Status-Message'] = 'Il cliente è stato avvertito'
       return original_response
```

In our method. However, while this works on our local setup, on heroku this generates a 500 error which we cannot figure out.

I've created a simple update method as follows:

```
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            original_response = Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
            original_response['X-Status-Type'] = 'info'
            original_response['X-Status-Message'] = 'Il cliente è stato avvertito'
            logger.info(original_response)
            return original_response
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e)
            logger.info('INSIDE CATCH')
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

With this one, PATCH call returns a 500 (internal server error...). Instead, with this method:

```
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            original_response = Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
            logger.info(original_response)
            return original_response
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e)
            logger.info('INSIDE CATCH')
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

i've got a 204 as a result.

It seems that the response is trapped on heroku's router and the 500 is generated there, which can be seen by this non-django response, even in debug mode:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Cowboy
Date: Thu, 18 Jun 2020 13:07:55 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 141
Via: 1.1 vegur

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Internal Server Error</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><p>Internal Server Error</p></h1>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A 500 is a *server error*, so that can be (nearly) everything. Are you sure the problem is with this piece of code? Not something else? Can you check the server logs?

Comment: 500 mean server error, you can try to put your API view into try catch and print out the exception

Comment: The same method without the additional headers (second and third rows commented) works

Comment: @LinhNguyen i've used a try-catch but no exceptions are logged

Comment: Question edited with additional informations